# Completed event for Ajax calls?

Tags: javascript, events, firefox, google-chrome

Is there some event that fires when an ajax request is completed? Even if it's not standard, as long it works on Firefox or Google Chrome.

Note: I didn't start the request, "someone else" did. It is not using jQuery.

---

The reason I want this is because websites like facebook aren't updating the whole page, so it doesn't fire the `window.onload`. This is becoming an issue to develop addons. It is hard to check the page and inject the script. If there were some event like `window.onajaxcompleted` it would be easier to inject the scripts.

I know there is one [event that check for DOM changes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4535531/340760), that is not exactly what I need, but it is one workaround.

Comment: @Felix: I wanted to sound like "I don't know how the request is being done, it can be anything". But I changed to be more clear.

Comment: So you're looking for an event that fires when *any* XMLHttpRequest object completes?

Comment: "Ajax" means "Making an HTTP request using JavaScript". Any event depends on the method used to perform the task, not the task itself.

Comment: What is your script doing? I.e. why does it have to know about new elements? Maybe there is another way to solve this.

Comment: @Felix change the page html (lets say: convert text links to html links) is one thing. I can't change on the `onload` event, because it is updated partially.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4535531/340760

Comment: If you're doing this from a Firefox addon then I believe you can trace all network activity and I think eventually relate it back to a window; if that's the window you're interested in you can then schedule a callback to perform the task.

Answer (score 1):

```
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
     alert('Success');
    }
  }
```

Comment: I didn't start the request. How am I supposed to get the `xmlhttp` object if I don't even know where it is...

Comment: I'm sorry but what is starting the request then?

Comment: Any custom script on a *unknown* page.